# Files missing after copying from one sdcard to another using Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, sd-card

I have two Kingston sdcards 8GB and 32GB. The 8GB for HTC Sensation and 32GB for my Tablet (Chinese). I soon ran out of space on my phone and decided to swap the data between the sdcards. I copied the data of 32GB sdcard to my PC(with Ubuntu 12.04) deleted everything on the 32GB sdcard and copied data from the 8GB sdcard to the other sdcard. At last I copied the data from my PC to the 8GB sdcard(before this I deleted everything that was on it before).

Now the problem is that the 8GB sdcard has the data exactly the same, but the 32GB sdcard has some missing data. All my photos(not copied or posted on Facebook) and Songs are lost.

Please help as to what I can do to get my data back?

I have Android Revolution HD (ICS 4.0.3) on my rooted HTC Sensation (India).
I suspect it has something to do with my data loss.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to give [Test Disk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk), or it's more photo-specific cousin [Photo Rec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec), a try.  Both are free and run on Linux (and just about every other OS).  They are able to scan through empty sections of the drive, even if the partition is gone, and recover recognizable files.  I have used PhotoRec before with great success (400+ photos recovered from a trashed partition, only about 10 lost).